# Privacy setting restfb poat

Tags: restfb

Im just starting to play a little with the restFb, I managed posting on my own page, but does anyone has any idea how to set the privacy of the post?

FacebookType publishPhotoResponse = facebookClient.publish("me/feed", FacebookType.class,
                Parameter.with("picture","img.png"),
                Parameter.with("message", "blablalala"),
Parameter.with("link","http://www.xyffffz.org"),Parameter.with("privacy.value","SELF")

I saw something on creating the Privacy object and including it, but Im having difficulties understanding some stuff.

Like lets say I created the object how do I set its attributes? the constructor is an empty one, maybe basic but....could use the help!

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage of privacy is:

`Parameter.with("privacy","{'value':'SELF'}")`